# Old obscure 90s cartoon

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon, video-games

There was a cartoon I used to watch as a kid in the 90s that had a featured two boys and I'm pretty sure a girl. They played a VR video game where an UFO would land and they'd go through waves of them. Then for some reason the aliens got a lot more difficult.

Later on there was an evil scientist or something that was controlling the game and used it to enslave the kids or something.

Comment: Can you expand a little more on what you mean by _"they'd go through waves of them"_? I assume you mean that the kids were taking down either the UFOs or the aliens, but which? And how?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of "The Last Starfighter".

Comment: Probably not it because it's not a cartoon, but it sounds a little like the second half of the first series of [The Demon Headmaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demon_Headmaster_(1996_TV_series)).